# Unitary irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I would like to know the Unitary irreducible representations (UIR) of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$. In [this](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.529994) paper I am studying right now, the author states (top of page 8) that the UIR's of $\mathbb{Z}$ are indexed by a number $s\in\mathbb{R} ~( \text{mod }  2)$ and are of the form $e^{\pi i s n}$ for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (at least this is my interpretation of what is said). What is meant by $s\in\mathbb{R}~(\text{mod }2)$? Does it mean that $s\in [0,2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that $s∈[0,2)$?

Essentially, yes, but that's not necessarily good way to think about it.

A unitary representation of $\mathbb{Z}$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ (under addition) to the complex plane (under multiplication) whose image lies on the unit circle. It's determined by the value it takes at $1$, which can be any point on the circle.

Points on the circle are naturally parameterized by the central angle, which varies from $0$ to $2\pi$. You can take out the factor of $\pi$ and parameterize by values between $0$ and $2$.

Comment: The UIR's of $\mathbb{R}$ are indexed by a number $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and are of the form $e^{itb}$ for a fixed $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Since both $\mathbb{R}$ and $[0,2)$ have the same cardinality, is the only difference between the two UIR's that the fixed numbers $n$ and $t$ take their values in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively?
$$$$
Why must $s\in [0,2)$ whilst $t$ is arbitrary? The exponential loops modulo $2\pi$ anyway...

Comment: so I guess I am asking why isn't $t\in [0,2\pi)$, since outside of that range it just repeats itself.

Comment: @NormalsNotFar No, $\exp(i tb)$ as a function of $t$ generally does *not* repeat itself for $t$ outside the range $[0,2\pi)$. Because $\exp(2\pi i b)$ may not equal $\exp(0)=1$. as $b$ can be anything in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @anon Ok, I think my confusion originates from not understanding the following sentence "It's determined by the value it takes at 1, which can be any point on the circle." May you please explain this to me, or link me to a ref that goes through the UIR's of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @NormalsNotFar This is a basic group theory fact. If $\phi:\Bbb Z\to G$ is any group homomorphism, then $\phi(n)=\phi(1)^n$, which means we know what $\phi$ is as a function on $\Bbb Z$ by just knowing the single value $\phi(1)$, and $\phi(1)$ can be any element $g\in G$ since  $\phi(n):=g^n$ is a well-defined group homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to G$ no matter what $g\in G$ is.

Comment: Thank you very much anon.